# $I(X)$ is a radical ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I didn't understand why if $X\subset \mathbb A^n$ is an affine algebraic set, then $I(X)$ is a radical ideal in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

I'm trying to understand this equivalence:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Because, if $f^n(x)=0$ for some $x \in \mathbb A^n$, then $f(x)=0$. This follows from the definition that $f^n(x)=(f(x))^n$. The correspondence in the other direction is the Hilbert Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @Doldrums so $I(X)$ is always radical, even when $X$ is not algebraic.

Comment: Indeed, $I(X)$ is always radical.

Comment: @Doldrums thanks for your help.

Comment: So why are answers written in comments again?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Comment now made into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comment made into an answer in response to Martin Brandenburg.

---

Because, if $f^n(x)=0$ for some $x\in \mathbb A^n$, then $f(x)=0$. This follows from the definition that $f^n(x)=(f(x))^n$. The correspondence in the other direction is the Hilbert Nullstellensatz.

Indeed, $I(X)$ is always radical, even when $X$ is not algebraic.